# AngularJS and TideSDK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tidesdk

I am trying to implement, an `AngularJS` App, to work with `TideSdk`. Everything works fine, if I run it over the browser, but however, I am not seeing any element loaded when I package it as a `TideSdk` application. The template is not even loading.

I don't find any useful as an error in the console.

Has anyone tried it before.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a project which is Angular based with TideSDK, and it's working well. All my routes, directives, services, (...), are working. Could you explain a bit more your issue?
Did you enable the webkit console of the app ? (https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Enabling-Web-Inspector  => for macos) 
All the logs are not present in the TideSDK Developper tool.